# Nested Unidirectional OnetoMany with Mapstruct Mapper interface returning null for the second level DTO class with

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapstruct

I have 4 classes with Unidirectional @OneToMany relationship as below:

```
Class A {
  // some properties
  List<B> bList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Class B has a Set of Class C

```
Class B {
   // Some properties
   Set<C> cSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Class C  has a One to One relationship with Class D

```
Class C {
   // Some properties here
   D d;
}
```

AMapper interface looks below;

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring", uses= {BMapper.class})
public interface AMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "aId", source="id")
    ADTO toDTO(final A a);

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    A toEntity(final ADTO aDTO);

}
```

BMapper as below:

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring", uses= {CMapper.class})
public interface BMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "bId", source="id")
    @Mapping(target = "xxx", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "yyy", ignore = true)
    BDTO toDTO(final BData entity);

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    B toEntity(final BDTO dto);

    Iterable<B> bDtoToBListEntity(Iterable<BDTO> list);

    Iterable<BDTO> bListEntityToBDto(Iterable<B> list);
 
    
 
}
```

CMapper as below

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { DMapper.class })
public interface CMapper {
    CDTO toDTO(C c);

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    C toEntity(CDTO planet);

    Set<C> cDtoToCSetEntity(Set<CDTO> set);

    Set<CDTO> cSetEntityToCDto(Set<C> set);
}
```

DMapper as below:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface DMapper {
    DDTO toDTO(D d);

    D toEntity(DDTO d);
}
```

```
@Service
AService {
    public ADTO get(final Long id) {
        return aMapper.toDTO( findById(id));
    }
}
```

What is the problem?
I am able to successfully read the bList when through the service class's get method however, cSet from class B is empty (not null though). Should I manually read the bDTO to populate the cSet? I hope not as I assume that's where the mapstruct is helping us. Any idea what is that I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: What `mapstruct` version are you using? I have copied your example, omitted the `Iterable` and `Set` methods you provided in `BMapper` and `CMapper` and created classes `A` and `ADto`. `mapstruct` maps `List`s and `Set`s pretty much the same way (iterate over the source, map one element, and add it to the target list). Have you checked the generated `MapperImpl` yet? When I encounter weird behavior with `mapstruct`, looking into the `MapperImpl` helps me pinpoint the issue. Also, are you by any chance utilizing `lombok` ?

Comment: Thanks @alamac777. You are right. The actual issue was outside the mapper code and after I fixed it, it is working fine now.